# Unsolicited response from Google Chat API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chat

I did so according to the instructions given [here](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces/get?hl=he) But the result is not desirable

```
function myFunction() {

  var url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAA*******'
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

And this is how the permissions look in the manifest

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.spaces"
]
```

But the result I got is an unwanted result

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.chat.v1.ChatService.GetSpace",
          "service": "chat.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What can cause a 401 error

**editing**

I wrote the permissions incorrectly the first time but that is not the cause of the problem because even if I write correctly the problem exists
I corrected above to the new code

Comment: That's not how you send the authorization token.  Where did you see that?

Comment: If your Google Apps Script project has permission for retrieving the values using "Method: spaces.get" from your endpoint, please modify `Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),` to `headers: { "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },`. In your script, please include `Authorization` property in the request header. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Comment: @Tanaike I don't understand why you say I do different from what you claim

Comment: @pini Thank you for replying. About `@Tanaike I don't understand why you say I do different from what you claim`, I apologize for my poor English skill and apologize that my comment was not useful.

Comment: @Tanaike Now I understand what you wanted. I wrote the code wrong but in the original it is correct look at the comment in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers need to be specified correctly:

```js
function myFunction() {

  var url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAA*******'
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
 
    // THIS
    headers: { 
      "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    },

    // NOT THIS
    // Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),

    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

Comment: I wrote the code wrong but in the original it is correct look at the comment in my question

Comment: I ran the above code and confirmed it works again today.